# How to filter table Pandas by some rules?

Tags: python, pandas

I try to filter rows which are true for the following conditions:

```
dataset = dataset[~dataset.duplicated(subset=['NUM'])]
dataset = [~dataset['NUM'].isin(invalidatedNumsDb)]
dataset = [dataset['NUM'].apply(checkNumber)]
dataset = [dataset['AGE'].apply(isAgeOld)]
dataset = [dataset['EMAIL'].apply(isEmail)]
```

Data is:

```
NUM AGE EMAIL
1   18  POPV@GMAIL.COM
2   N   APA@GMAIL.COM
3   20   APAR@GMAIL.COM
```

As reult I want to get the prev table with rows:

```
3   20   APAR@GMAIL.COM
```

Because 20 is true for `isAgeOld`
APAR@GMAIL.COM is true for `isEmail`
3 is true for `checkNumber` and 3 is not presented in set `invalidatedNumsDb`.

Problem is if `[~dataset['NUM'].isin(invalidatedNumsDb)]` returns true it contains result:

```
[0    False
 Name: NUM, dtype: bool]
```

Then the next rule is fails:

```
dataset = [dataset['NUM'].apply(checkNumber)]

invalidatedNumsDb = {1,2}

def checkNumber(v):
  v < 100

def isAgeOld(v):
   return v > 18

def isEmail(v):
   return True
```

Comment: Include `invalidatedNumsDb`, `isAgeOld`, 'isEmail` and `checkNumber` in your question so we can run your code.

Comment: Okay, just now I do

Comment: I want to filter all rows by rules above and get result dataframe it can be empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `checkNumber` function to actually `return` a value. Then apply your conditions to your dataset:

```
def checkNumber(v):
  return v < 100

m1 = ~dataset.duplicated("NUM")
m2 = ~dataset['NUM'].isin(invalidatedNumsDb)
m3 = dataset['NUM'].apply(checkNumber)
m4 = pd.to_numeric(dataset['AGE'],errors='coerce').apply(isAgeOld)
m5 = dataset['EMAIL'].apply(isEmail)

output = dataset[m1&m2&m3&m4&m5]

>>> output 
   NUM AGE           EMAIL
2    3  20  APAR@GMAIL.COM
```

Comment: I think problem in `dataset = [~dataset['NUM'].isin(invalidatedNumsDb)]` it return empty dataframe then the last rules not working

Comment: The above code works.

Comment: I did return in function the same error. Because I have one row and it is presented in invalidatedNumsDb. It means I get empty dataframe

Comment: It should be `m2 = ~dataset['NUM'].isin(invalidatedNumsDb)` true, I need to check if there is a NUM in dict `invalidatedNumsDb`. If exists then exclude this row

Comment: That's what `m2` does - if the NUM is in your set, it ignores that row. I don't understand your question.

Comment: If `NUM` already exist in `invalidatedNumsDb` I have to skip this row. Now it has

Comment: It does skip it. In your example, 1 and 2 are invalid, so they're not in the output. Why is this so confusing for you?